# Sort single object with dynamic keys/values

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, lodash

Trying to find optimal and working version how to sort single object by it's dynamic keys or values. The sorting has to be case insensitive but display capital letters.

Given:

```
const givenInput = {  
  C1: "C 1",
  a0: "a 0",
  a1: "a 1",
  a2: "a 2",
  a6: "a 6",
  a7: "a 7",
  aB: "a B",
  a3: "a 3",
  sdasdA: "sdasd A",
  aA: "a A",
  aC: "a C",
  aD: "a D",
  a4: "a 4",
  a5: "a 5",
  b1: "b 1",
  sdasd0: "sdasd 0",
  sdasd1: "sdasd 1",
  sdasdB: "sdasd B",
}
```

Expected

```
const expectedOutput = { 
  a0: "a 0",
  a1: "a 1",
  a2: "a 2",
  a3: "a 3",
  a4: "a 4",
  a5: "a 5",
  a6: "a 6",
  a7: "a 7",
  aA: "a A",
  aB: "a B",
  aC: "a C",
  aD: "a D",
  b1: "b 1",.
  C1: "C 1",
  sdasd0: "sdasd 0",
  sdasd1: "sdasd 1",
  sdasdA: "sdasd A",
  sdasdB: "sdasd B",
}
```

Lodash can be used too

Comment: [Objects do not guarantee key order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Maybe you want to sort the output of Object.entries(givenInput) ?

Comment: This will work, `Object.entries(givenInput).sort((a,b)=>a[0].localeCompare(b[0])).map(a=>a.join(':')).join('\n')`. As Jo suggested, you can sort the entries by their keys (index 0).

Comment: This would work too I think: `const result = Object.entries(givenInput).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => k1.localeCompare(k2));`